# Get error on creating MessageConnection on specific port?

Tags: java, java-me, s60, wma, midp-2.0

I have **java-j2me-midp2** application. In this app there is a part which listen to **SMS-Inbox** and do operation in app base on these sms.
For this section we use  `MessageConnection`, we create it with below code:

```
   try {
            msgConnection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://:" + port);
            msgConnection.setMessageListener(Listener);
       } 
   catch (Exception e)
       {
            showexception(0, p.error_listen);
       }
```

After several time we use that app(*and worked without exception*), currently we got error on this section *(even on different ports)*.

> **Error :** Java.IO.IOException  Symbian OS Error=-1

As you can see this error,it happen on Symbian OS phone(like NokiaE52, Nokia5800, Sony Ericsson Vivaz). These phone use Symbian series60.

***Q:*** Am I miss something? Is there better way for doing this? Why this **Error** happen? any Tips?